# websphere liberty on docker container

Tags: java, docker, websphere-liberty

I'm running a docker container by the image websphere-liberty:webProfile7. I've installed adminCenter, modified the server.xml of defaultServer as shown at https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/features-com.ibm.websphere.appserver.adminCenter-1.0 then restarted the server, but I continue to can not access the adminCenter or the login page. When i go on my 192.168.99.100:80/admincenter I see a websphere page tha says me "Context Root Not Found".
What's the problem?

Comment: The logs are under /logs folder.  Can you check if it shows any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you modify the port to set it to 80?  Default http port is 9080 and https is 9443, so if you haven't changed them you want either http://192.168.99.100:9080/adminCenter or https://192.168.99.100:9443/adminCenter
Also, note that the context root is 'adminCenter' (camelCase) and not 'admincenter'

You can also go to http://{hostname}:{httpPort} or https://{hostname}:{httpsPort} which should show the Liberty splash page.  If Admin Center is installed (and a connection to wasdev.net is available from your machine) there should be a link to it ("Open Admin Center").
[image]

Comment: After a second read, since you're seeing a Liberty 'Context root not found' it sounds like you did indeed change the http port, so the issue is just 'admincenter' instead of 'adminCenter'

Comment: thank for the answer. I find usefull it, and I also fond some little errors in server.xml file. Now it works.

Comment: at this moment 192.168.99.100 shows as your picture, but when I click on Open Admin Center, firefox poit to 192.168.99.100/adminCenter, but it seems as the page is unreachable

Comment: I'm guessing the url that you're using actually includes the port right?  Also, are you accessing the server from same machine (aka, is the client/browser on the same machine as the server)? 
I'd also take a look at the server's messages.log to see if there's any warnings/errors.

Comment: I'm working with docker container. The browser is the one of my local physical machine and the docker container is running in a local installation of docker platform (think it coulb be named as "server docker deamon"). However I solved the proble creating a brand new container of Websphere-liberty and in the server.xml file I didn't insert the tags about keystore. It now works pretty fine.